# How to filter nested data in computed data (VueJS)?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

The idea is pretty simple.

In a computed variable, I want to filter sections using needle, but instead of just displaying matched sections and attached questions (like in my example below), I want to exclude questions where title doesn't match AND section title doesn't match.

Here is the initial set of datas :

```js
const sections = 
  [
    {
      title: 'Title section 1',
      questions : [
        {
          title: 'Title question 1'
        },
        {
          title: 'Title question 2'
        }
      ]
     },
    {
      title: 'Title section 2',
      questions : [
        {
          title: 'Title question 3'
        },
        {
          title: 'Title question 4'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Here is the expected results :

When needle is "section 1" :

```js
const filteredArray = [  
  {
    title: 'Title section 1',
    questions : [
      {
        title: 'Title question 1'
      },
      {
        title: 'Title question 2'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When needle is "question 1" :

```js
const filteredArray = [  
  {
    title: 'Title section 1',
    questions : [
      {
        title: 'Title question 1'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And so on.

Here is the code I've written :

```js
const sections = 
  [
    {
      title: 'Title section 1',
      questions : [
        {
          title: 'Title question 1'
        },
        {
          title: 'Title question 2'
        }
      ]
     },
    {
      title: 'Title section 2',
      questions : [
        {
          title: 'Title question 3'
        },
        {
          title: 'Title question 4'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

const needle = 'question 4'
  
 
const filteredArray = sections.filter(section => section.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1 ||
        section.questions.filter(question => question.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1).length > 0)
        
console.log(filteredArray)
```

As you can see, filtered results are good, but I'm not able to exclude questions when question title AND section title doesn't match.

An idea ?

**NB :** I'm using vuejs 2, so my original array is comming from the store, and to keep reactivity, I can't use an other array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @dhilt, here is the final solution :)

```js
const sections = 
  [
    {
      title: 'Title section 1',
      questions : [
        {
          title: 'Title question 1'
        },
        {
          title: 'Title question 2'
        }
      ]
     },
    {
      title: 'Title section 2',
      questions : [
        {
          title: 'Title question 3'
        },
        {
          title: 'Title question 4'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

const needle = 'question 4'
const filteredArray = sections.reduce((acc, section) => {
  // Pushing entire section if we find needle in section title
  if (section.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    acc.push({ ...section })
  } else {
    // Pushing section with filtered questions when question title match
    const questions = section.questions.filter(question =>
      question.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    )
    if (questions.length > 0) {
      acc.push({ ...section, questions })
    }
  }
  return acc
}, [])
console.log(filteredArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Array.prototype.reduce to achieve such a result:

```
const needleTitle = 'section 2'
const needleQuestion = 'question 4'

const filteredArray = sections.reduce((acc, section) => {
  // filtering 1-level section list by pushing to acc only needed items
  if (section.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(needleTitle.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
    // filtering 2-level question list by replacing section.questions with a new list
    const questions = section.questions.filter(question => 
      question.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(needleQuestion.toLowerCase()) >= 0
    )
    acc.push({ ...section, questions });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Also, you see, I splitted `needle` to `needleTitle` and `needleQuestion`. Probably it is not exactly what you want, but the idea should be useful. The code above will result

```
[  
  {
    title: 'Title section 2',
    questions : [
      {
        title: 'Title question 4'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! 

Unfortunatly it doesn't work, because of the assertion _section.questions_. As I mentionned above, I'm working with datas comming from the store, and then I've got this error : _[vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers._. 

If I use commits tu mutate section.questions, I lose the original data

Comment: @Logane Oh, this is not a big problem, I updated the answer to eliminate unnecessary mutations. Now we are pushing to the result array a copy of `section` object with it's own question list.

Comment: Great, I've posted the final code. It works like a charm, thanks for help !